# Highlight specific days of a week in jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

my aim is to highlight specific days of a week in jQuery datepicker.

For example I want to highlight Tuesdays and Thursdays. I've seen many examples how to highlight specific dates(see: **http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/05/highlight-specific-dates-in-jquery-ui.html**). But not a single one that covers my needs.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adapt the example you linked, to do what you want, like this:

CSS:

```
.Highlighted a{
   background-color : Green !important;
   background-image :none !important;
   color: White !important;
   font-weight:bold !important;
   font-size: 12pt;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            if (day == 2 || day == 4) {
                return [true, "Highlighted", date];
            }
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    });
});​
```

that should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with only CSS using the `+` adjacent selector if you can assume the week starts on Sunday. It may look a little ridiculous but it will work in any browser that supports `+` and `:first-child` (Which includes IE7 and up).

```
/* Tuesday:                Su               Mo   Tu            */
.ui-datepicker-calendar tr td:first-child + td + td a,
/* Thursday:               Su               Mo   Tu   We   Th  */
.ui-datepicker-calendar tr td:first-child + td + td + td + td a {
    background:red;
}
​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jnGhV/1/

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtDate').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            if(date.getDay() == 2 || date.getDay() == 4) {
                return [true, "Highlighted", ''];
            } else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }

        }
    });
});​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XuExp/

Comment: thank you yery much for your answer! but i can only accept one answer. since all of the answers are correct i choose the first one. sorry!